# Unable to install xcode 8.3.2 on virtual machine of mac os 10.10.5

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm new to xcode iOS development, trying to develop an app for iOS version 10.2+ . I have installed a Mac OS 10.10.5 on my Windows using vmWare(version 12). I tried searching for latest version of iOS 10.12 Sierra iso image but was unable to find it.

Now, the problem is Mac OS 10.10.5 supports xcode 7.2.1 which is used to to develop apps upto iOS 9.2 .

Is there any alternative I can use to run my app on the iOS 10.2+ without using a simulator.

Finally I want to develop an app for iOS version 10.2+ .

Comment: You need to search better, I got the newest Mac on my VMWare running, but I do not think I can posts links or brands here from where I downloaded

Answer (score -1):

Try to install xcode 8.3.2 in Mac os 10.12.